# Mule Cloudhub Anypoint MQ - Configuring exclusive access to individual queues

Tags: mule-esb, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

we are using Anypoint MQ. We are looking for options to configure access to individual queues exclusively, so that they are accessible to only certain apps. But, based on our research it looks like - with anypoint credentials we can browse messages from all the queues.

Can you please help us if exclusive queue access credentials can be configured? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use business groups or environments to restrict access according to the FAQ: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-faq#how-can-i-restrict-access-to-a-queue-or-message-exchange